# Oracle SQL Developer - How to Restrict User to See Only Specific Schemas

Tags: oracle11g, schema, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-schema

In Oracle DB 11g, using SQL Developer, I created a user with an associated schema that has only read-only privileges. Now I want to restrict that new user from being able to VIEW the other users/schemas except for a few that I select.

In other words, when they (in SQL Developer) go to the "Other Users" folder under their own schema, I don't want that user to be able to see ALL the Other Users that are on that database. I only want to them to see a few select ones.

How do you do that if possible?

Btw... I know that I can restrict them from being able to do anything to those other users (e.g. create tables, run queries, etc...).  However, I want to prevent them from even VIEWING or SEEING that those other users are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you can only do in SQL Developer what you can otherwise do in the database.

As Alex has said, SQL Developer uses a SELECT from SYS.ALL_USERS to see all the users in the system. This is not an SQL Developer issue; your user, if they had access to SQL*Plus, could run `select username from sys.all_users` directly against the database and get the same information.

Removing that information from your user follows the same path. One can only SELECT from tables on which they were granted the SELECT privilege. Selecting from catalog tables and views (and specifically from ALL_USERS in the SYS schema) is usually an indirect grant: the PUBLIC role has the privilege to SELECT from these tables, and in most cases (perhaps by default? depending on your admin tool) new users are granted the PUBLIC role.

Depending on your business needs, you may either REVOKE the PUBLIC role from selected users (and then create bundles of privileges you want to grant them, to replace what they lose this way), or - more drastically, and perhaps not something you should do - you can simply `revoke select on all_users from public;` (while logged in with SYSDBA privilege, or some other privilege sufficient to perform this operation).

**Edit** - I just checked, and unfortunately one cannot revoke the PUBLIC role; it is automatically granted to all users in the database and that can't be changed. This leaves only the less desirable alternative of messing with the privileges PUBLIC itself has. **End edit**

I just tested this - I logged in `as sysdba`, revoked select on SYS.ALL_USERS from PUBLIC, then shut down SQL Developer and restarted it. Sure enough, I am no longer able to see any "other users" from any of the custom users I created in my database (meaning, from SQL Developer connections I created for those users).

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @ptownbro - please note my **Edit** - unfortunately PUBLIC cannot be taken away from users; the only solution is to revoke SELECT on SYS.ALL_USERS from PUBLIC, which may have nasty effects on other users (and, quite likely, on processes and applications that may need to access that table).

Answer (score 3):

You can't, essentially. If you look at the statement log in SQL Developer as you expand the 'other users' section in the connections panel, you'll see the command it's using is:

```
select * from (select USERNAME
FROM SYS.ALL_USERS au
WHERE au.USERNAME != USER
 );
```

A brand new user which has only been granted connect privileges can see all users listed from that system view.

As that query is qualifying the `all_users` object name with the `sys` schema you can't even create a view or private synonym for your user that gives a restricted list. Though of course the user would be able to sidestep that if they wanted to anyway.

SQL Developer does let you filter things in the connections pane. If you right-click on 'other users' and choose 'apply filter...' you'll see a dialog like:

[image: apply filter dialog]

You could set that up with 'match any' and all the schemas you do want to be visible, clicking the green plus sign to add more. Only those users would then be shown under 'other users'. When you expand 'other users' the statement log shows this modified query instead:

```
select * from (select USERNAME
FROM SYS.ALL_USERS au
WHERE au.USERNAME != USER
 ) WHERE (UPPER(USERNAME) = (UPPER(:SCHEMA)) OR UPPER(USERNAME) = (UPPER(:SCHEMA0)))
```

... and it shows the bind parameters are `"SCHEMA"="SOUSER1", "SCHEMA0"="SOUSER2"`

But you can't control that centrally, you would have to set it up on everyone's copy of SQL Developer (probably manually, though you could look at supplying a config file), and the users can easily remove or change the filter. It affects the client rather than the user, and again can easily be sidestepped.

Comment: Grrr. Ok. So even if I apply the filter on my end, it won't show on their end?  Is that what you mean it can't be controlled centrally?

Comment: Yes, changing the filters or preferences on your client (i.e. SQL Developer on your PC) won't affect anyone else. If you can find the right config file and the bit that relates to filters you could maybe find a way to distribute it, but not easily. (Oracle does have VPD... but I'm not sure if can (or should) be applied to system views; might be something to look into to make sure...)

Comment: If you are interested - this is a database issue, not an SQL Developer issue. I explain further in an Answer I just posted.

Comment: Yes, that's what the first half of my answer is saying; only the second half is about SQL Developer. I'd be reluctant to mess with sys objects or privs though, even synonyms in case anything else internal assumes they are there (EM queries, for instance, though most would presumably access objects directly, as SD does).

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If a new user must be prevented from seeing who other users are, then he shouldn't be granted the PUBLIC role. Instead, the OP can create a new role with fewer privileges and grant that to new users. I don't see that as messing with any sys objects. My point with this is that security should be enforced in the database itself, not in the front-end tier.

Comment: And another part of my answer is to, in essence, disagree with the statement *A brand new user which has only been granted connect privileges can see all users listed from that system view.* Connect privileges do not include SELECT on anything; that is most likely attained by granting PUBLIC role to new users.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that, as I said it can be sidestepped anyway otherwise. A user doesn't need to have public granted explicitly - I did create a new user and *only* granted create - so it would have to be removed somehow (if that's even possible; can't remember off-hand) as you said in your answer. I was referring more to the second half, removing something *from* public, which you also warned against. As usual I think we're agreeing really...

Comment: Ugh... good point, and I edited my answer to clarify: one cannot "revoke" the PUBLIC role, all users in the database have that role (it doesn't need to be "granted" since that's automatic) and there is no way to take it away. The only remaining solution is indeed to mess with the role itself, which may have undesirable cascading effects. I learned a few more things by researching this question! :-)

Comment: I wish Oracle would just fix this. I have to access many databases and "schemas" (I mean Oracle schemas, not normal schemas) and it's super inconvenient going through a huge list of "schemas" I cannot even access.